# Why do the NMR peaks shift when H+ concentration and temperature are varied on the reversible hydrolysis of pyruvic acid to 2,2-dihydroxypropionate?

Tags: kinetics, nmr-spectroscopy

We performed two experiments. Each of the peaks are referring to the methyl peaks in both reactant and product of the hydrolysis reaction.

1. We varied $\ce{H+}$ concentration of the reaction and the peaks move ever so slightly right (up field) as acid concentration increases. Why?

   As more acid is added there is more pyruvic acid present than the hydrate. But pyruvic acid is more deshielded, so I would have expended it to shift downfield because more deshielded molecules are present.
2. We varied temperature (45, 50, 55, 60 and 65 °C) and the peaks move slightly left (down field) as temperature is increased. Why?

   The only possible explanations I can come up with are that the temperature changes conformations in a way that is more deshielded, but I don't know why specifically?

Comment: What nucleus are you monitoring? What is the solvent, pH etc

Comment: Ask yourself: generally speaking, what does it mean when a nucleus becomes deshielded? If you know what that means, you are probably in as good a position as anyone to propose a cause.

Comment: Proton NMR, My hydrogen ion concentrations are: 0.000E+00, 4.444E-04, 8.889E-04, 1.333E-03, 1.778E-03, 2.222E-03

Comment: I understand that shielding is relating to electron density, but I am still note sure why they would shift, based solely on changes in temperature and acid concentration

Comment: I would begin by looking at the inductive effect of different groups and attempting to rationalize the observations in terms of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_effect#Inductive_effect

Comment: I recommend you add some spectra to illustrate the observations. As it stands there are dynamic effects that would not be easy to describe in words but would be quite apparent if you show a series of spectra (as function of pH or temperature). You don't need to show the entire spectra, just the properly referenced methyl region.

Comment: Like, you want the NMR spectra???

Comment: Sure, you can take screenshots of overlayed spectra, emphasizing methyl region. You don't have to do this, but I strongly think (can't be sure) that it might help to clarify what is happening.

Comment: I . dont have the spectra, they were on a computer and we just recorded the numebrs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101202/discussion-between-harley-mcfarlen-and-buck-thorn).